# How to add entries in web.xml of a Rest Application(A1) for a different Rest Service Application,(A2), if A2 is present as JAR in lib of A1?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

How to add entries in web.xml of a Rest Application, say App1 for a different Rest Service Application, say APP2 which is  placed in Web-Inf/lib of APP1 as APP2.jar file. Is it possible using Jersey?

I Provided the listener Package name of APP2 under web.xml of App1 as follows:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.test.check.ws.Service,     //package under APP1
        com.test2.conditions.rest      // package under App2
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

APP1 resource is up and running but APP2 resource is saying 404.